# Microsoft Outlook 2010 signature update

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

Is there a tool or a way to update/change the signature in the Microsoft outlook 2010 (Like write a script), using windows 7 x64 for all users by running a tool or script instead of changing or updating each user individually?

Or to change it from an Microsoft exchange 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can change or add a corporate signature at the Exchange server level. The signature is a client-side setting however and the user will still be able to set and/or change their signature unless you restrict them via GPO.

> - Open the Exchange Management Console.
> - In  Organization Configuration select Hub Transport and then select
>     the Transport Rules tab.
> - In the Actions Pane click New Transport Rule…
> - Name your rule and optionally add a Comment. For instance; Name:
>     Corporate signature Comment: This transport rule adds a standardized
>     signature and disclaimer text to all outgoing emails.
> - Press Next.
> - On the Conditions screen select the following 2 conditions;
>
>   - From users that are inside or outside the organization
>   - Sent to users that are inside or outside the organization, or
>       partners
> - In the bottom pane, modify the conditions so that they read;
>
>   - From users that are Inside the organization
>   - And sent to users that are Outside the organization
> - Press Next.
> - In the Actions screen select the action;
>
>   - Append disclaimer text and fall back to action if unable to apply.
> - In the bottom pane you can modify the conditions to your preference.
>
>   - Click on disclaimer text to insert your default disclaimer text and    add variables to include user information (see below for an
>       overview    of variables which you can use).
>   - Note that the disclaimer text allows you to use HTML code (including    in-line CSS). This will allow you for instance to set
>       different font    size and colors for the signature and disclaimer
>       part, add a    horizontal line, hyperlink text or include a logo.
>   - You can use up to 5000 characters
>   - When a Plain Text message is sent, the HTML tags are automatically    stripped off.
> - Once done, press Next.
> - You can set any exception as you see fit. You can continue without    any exceptions as well.
> - Press Next.
> - On the Create Rule screen you’ll see the PowerShell command that will    be executed when clicking the New button.
> - After pressing the New button the wizard has been completed and a    summary is shown. Assuming it completed successfully, your Transport
>     Rule has been created and is active now. Clicking Finish will close
>     the New Transport Rule dialog.

Ref: http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm